# Are there multiple instances of Ethereum state or a single latest image?

Tags: state-trie, architecture

Are there multiple instances of Ethereum's state? That is, is there one per mined block? Or a single latest image?

Does Ethereum maintain a state snapshot, for every block since genesis, so that previous states can be checked?

Answer (score 4):

The ethereum state is stored on disk in a merkle tree separate from the actual data of the blockchain (ie. the blocks of transactions). The state is not included in blocks - only the state root is included in the block. The state is immutable, so each time an update is made, the old value is not deleted but persists on disk. Old values can be accessed by loading the merkle tree associated with an older state root. Storing all this old data is quite wasteful, of course, and so there are some efforts to "prune" the state tree so it only keeps the most recent data (or say the data from the last X blocks).

See https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/06/26/state-tree-pruning/